# Getting Wireless working on Dell Inspiron 1545 in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: drivers, wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04, dell-inspiron, broadcom

I'm trying to install my wireless drivers (which uses a broadcom card). I tried to install them using the restricted drivers offered on my Ubuntu CD (since my only internet connection is public Wi-Fi). However when I clicked activate it got about halfway through the install process before it gave me this error message:

> `SystemError:  installArchives() failed`

The driver in question is this one: `Broadcom STA wireless driver`

How can I correct this?

Comment: So it fixed itself? I'm not sure how but as of today I turned on my PC and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Broadcom wireless also, it isn't that good but it get the job done. I think it would be better if we could know the exact model, because depending that you will need a driver or another:

> lspci

Also it would be nice to have the

> dmesg | tail

output for knowing what error is exactly.

But anyways, there are a lot of options involving this chipset: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: The model number reported from the output of lspci is `bcm4312`, but as I said in my comment on my question, now the wireless card is working.

Comment: I gave the bounty to you because I figured you were on the right trail.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

10.04 is still in beta. I would try 9.10 Live, if you can get it working on that one you know that it's a problem with 10.04. If that's the case, than you could file a bug report about 10.04 and you're card.

Comment: I tried 9.10 and it didn't work so I uninstalled it. I figured 10.04 would have that fixed, but of course they didn't.

Comment: http://bcm43xx.berlios.de/?go=devices

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I discovered that the "patch" package wasn't installed, and that's where the kernel source build was failing.  Installed that and it worked.

Comment: Would be nice if you could mark this as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Ubuntu 10.04 I had the exact same problem! To solve it:

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager
2. Type "broadcom"
3. Right click on "bcmwl-kernel-source" and mark it for re-installation
4. Go back to the hardware drivers where you should now be able to activate the broadcom driver without any problems.